# Drive Scope for Ubuntu

Tags: authentication

I keep getting a pop up asking me to authenticate drive scope for Ubuntu - when i allow access all it does is take me to the Ubuntu Wiki site which does not seem relevent at all, when i try to get rid of it by pressing the X or i decline access to my Google account it just keeps coming back over and over and persists on restart, its becoming quite annoying. How can i prevent it from bothering me?

I have tried accepting, declining, restarting and updating everything but it just persists.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-scope-gdrive && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Restart your computer.

This will remove the Google Drive Scope/Lens/Plug-in (whatever it's called) from your computer.